# OpalRB Ignore compile directive

Tags: opalrb

I'm building an application that will be hosted both as a stand-alone app as well as running within the web browser. This means that certain classes should be implemented differently (but used in the same way). Example:

```
If OPAL_RB
  require 'javascript_aware_lib'
else
  require 'native_lib'
end
```

The problem with this is, Ruby will evaluate this at run-time, but Opal will evaluate it at compile time. If this was not so, I could simply use a rescue clause:

```
begin   
  RUBY_ENGINE_VERSION
  #opal requires goes here
rescue
  # MRI Ruby requires goes here 
end
```

So, to put things simply: Is there any kind of directive or work-around to keep Opal from evaluating a block of code? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use `unless RUBY_ENGINE == 'opal'`, which is actually skipped at compilation time. This makes it effective to skip also unsupported syntax. `if`, `else` and `RUBY_PLATFORM` are also supported.

Example:

```
if RUBY_ENGINE == 'opal'
  require 'javascript_aware_lib'
else
  require 'native_lib'
end
```

---

#### Some relevant code (for the curious)

Compiler handling the AST: https://github.com/opal/opal/blob/ef570e3ddde9bddc48cc0f94c00e80576140850f/lib/opal/nodes/if.rb#L10-L15

Changelog: https://github.com/opal/opal/blob/8a023f057799fd68fecb3371b52950c7392d469c/CHANGELOG.md#060-2014-03-05

Specs: https://github.com/opal/opal/blob/0aef3c6c7a5db8ff86c8f786a5ea6885ea2b12dc/spec/cli/compiler_spec.rb#L86-L121

Answer (score 0):

I just found this code

```
if defined?(Opal) && defined?(File)  
  Opal.append_path File.expand_path('.', File.dirname(__FILE__))
end
```

in [this interesting blogpost](http://blog.crossplatformruby.com/universal-ruby-gems-in-20-lines-of-code/?utm_source=rubyweekly&utm_medium=email) on writing cross ruby gems for MRI, opalrb and RubyMotion. Might be interesting for you as well. It uses the presence of the `Opal` class to determine the ruby interpreter.

Comment: The post is good but the code is quite weak, I already wrote to the author to fix it by relying on `RUBY_ENGINE` instead.